# Batch job on Google Cloud Platform using Docker image has out-of-memory error before even starting

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm using google cloud platform's batch feature to run containers in parallel and, in certain regions, after a while, I wind up hitting this error:

```json
  {
    "textPayload": "docker: Error response from daemon: mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/8000fd83d3d88faf613413bc2bf93c89664bfc45daf4e0f3783e4a754f02a27f-init: no space left on device.\nSee 'docker run --help'.\n",
    "insertId": "10wsnp3f2rht1y",
    "resource": {
      "type": "generic_task",
      "labels": {
        "task_id": "task/j-9b13c8c6-9371-4d43-b000-ce596b1bcac0-group0-3634/0/0",
        "job": "j-9b13c8c6-9371-4d43-b000-ce596b1bcac0",
        "project_id": "ml-experiments-379111",
        "namespace": "",
        "location": "europe-west6-c"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2023-03-02T20:23:35.566591749Z",
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "labels": {
      "hostname": "j-9b13c8c6-9371-4d43-b000-ce596b1bcac0-group0-0-2ss2",
      "job_uid": "j-9b13c8c6-9371-4d43-b000-ce596b1bcac0",
      "task_group_name": "projects/486015383666/locations/europe-west6/jobs/cpuart-real-50000-60000/taskGroups/group0"
    },
    "logName": "projects/ml-experiments-379111/logs/batch_task_logs",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2023-03-02T20:23:35.587286849Z"
  }
```

The jobs are all identical save the final artifact generated, which varies nominally in content but not in size. So I doubt the actual batch job is causing this, and also, there are no logs from the job (it starts with a sanity-check log that doesn't appear in these logs).

All this would lead me to believe that google cloud platform batch spins up an image that, for whatever reason, has a `/tmp` directory into which docker has already written something. If this is the case, is there a good workaround? I could, for example, nuke the `/tmp` dir from the script that's being executed in batch, but it seems that it doesn't even get there.

About 50% of my jobs are failing due to this, so it'd be helpful to sort out. Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Answer (score 1):

The issue turned out to be that the files I've created (around 1gb) aren't wiped between successive invocations of batch jobs. By deleting these files as the last step of my job, that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Docker engine uses `/var/lib/docker` to store the images and container runtime environment. Looks like the disk mounted to `/var/lib/docker` is full. You can verify the size using the command `du -sh /var/lib/docker`.

These are possible resolutions:

1. Mount a disk with a good amount of space based on the number of images & applications you are running.
2. Remove unused images or stopped containers completely to obtain some free space.Few commands that helps are

   `$ docker image rm <image-name/image-id>`

   `$ docker container rm <container-name/container-id>`

You can run the below command to do some cleanup.

```
docker system prune --all --force
```

To delete volumes currently not being used by a running or stopped container:

```
docker system prune --all --force --volumes
```

For more information you can refer to the document [Disk capacity errors](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-disk-full-resize#disk_capacity_errors) and [Docker commands](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've done this sort of thing before on infra that I managed, but I'm not sure how to do it on the servers that GCP batch provides. Is there a way to prune the servers before they attempt to run a batch job?

Comment: Where are you running this Batch job? Is it on GKE or Compute Instance.